# Is there a way to get string representation of boolean option in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm using [AppendModeline](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic#Adding_a_modeline) function to add a modeline to my vim files:

```
" Append modeline after last line in buffer.
" Use substitute() instead of printf() to handle '%%s' modeline in LaTeX
" files.
function! AppendModeline()
  let l:modeline = printf(" vim: set ts=%d sw=%d tw=%d :",
        \ &tabstop, &shiftwidth, &textwidth)
  let l:modeline = substitute(&commentstring, "%s", l:modeline, "")
  call append(line("$"), l:modeline)
endfunction
```

But I want to extend it. It shall support adding the current value of **expandtab**.
Using **&expandtab**, I can get a numeric representation of the current value. But something like **set et=0** isn't supported by vim. It has to be **set [no]expandtab**.
Do I really have to test for *&expandtab* and append *expandtab* or *noexpandtab* to *l:modeline* or is there a way to get a string representation of the current value?
**set expandtab?** shows *[no]expandtab*, but I don't know how to use this in a script (or if it's even possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to do this. With `:redir` it is possible to capture output, but `:redir`-based solution is at least four lines long with regex to grab the value. Using `&et` is much cleaner:

```
… printf("… %set …", …, &expandtab ? '' : 'no', …)
```

Note: `%set` is `%s` followed by `et` (short for `expandtab`). Word `set` here is just an accident.